# "bfd library not found" error when configuring Oprofile

Tags: ubuntu, profiling, oprofile

I downloaded oprofile zip and then extracted it. Then using the command

```sh
./configure --prefix=/home/eranga/Software/oprofile-1.1.0
```

I tried to install it. Below are the last console messages.

```sh
checking for bfd_openr in -lbfd... no
checking for compress in -lz... yes
checking for bfd_fdopenr in -lbfd... no
configure: error: bfd library not found
```

Can anyone suggest why this is happening and a solution to it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like you are missing a library. This command installs `bfd` library for me:

```sh
sudo apt-get install binutils-dev
```